# Broadcast receiver not registered

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I am having an error where I register a broadcast receiver in the constructor. However, when I unregister it in `onPause` it throws an exception about not being registered. How can this be and can you help me solve the problem.

The main problem is that I am bound to a `NetworkService` class, which I also can't unbind from. It gives problems when I restart the app and says that I have a "leak". But I don't know which of the two problems generating the leak.

Here is my code:

**Constants**

```
private static NetworkService networkService;
private ServiceConnection networkServiceConnection;
private BroadcastReceiver networkServiceMessageReceiver;
private boolean boundToService;
```

**OnCreate**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    /** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    networkServiceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder service) {
            NetworkService.LocalBinder binder = (NetworkService.LocalBinder) service;
            networkService = binder.getService();
            boundToService = true;

            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(SplashActivity.this).registerReceiver(networkServiceMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(NetworkService.CHECK_FOR_UPDATE_RESULT));
            checkForUpdate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            boundToService = false;
        }
    };
}
```

**OnResume**

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //Bind to NetworkService
    if(!boundToService)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NetworkService.class);
        bindService(intent, networkServiceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
}
```

**OnPause**

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    unregisterReceiver(networkServiceMessageReceiver);
}
```

**OnStop**

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    unbindService(networkServiceConnection);
}
```

Comment: make registration /unregistration in pairs: create/destroy or start/stop or resume/pause

Comment: So if I register i in onCreate I should unregister in onDestroy?

Comment: yes,  but its better to narrow the lifecycle to start/stop or even resume/pause

Comment: btw if your receiver is just to listen from service then you should use bound service which you are using already

Comment: How do I then receive the message if I dont listen for it?

Comment: is it a local bound service? or in separate remote process ?

Comment: ok its local as you are using LocalBroadcastManager, then after connection is made, call a service (name it registerCallback()) with a callback reference, then service can call you back, before unbindService call unregisterCallbak() so your service knows you are no longer interested with updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `unregisterReceiver()` on the `Activity` context, but you are calling `registerReceiver()` on the `LocalBroadcastManager` context. This can't work. You need to register and unregister on the same `Context`.

Make sure you only unregister if your `Service` has already been bound, otherwise you won't have called `register()`.

Also, since you are unregistering in `onPause()` you need to reregister in `onResume()`.

Answer (score 0):

> I am having an error where I register a broadcast receiver in the constructor. However, when I unregister it in onPause it throws an exception abaout not being registered.

You are registering your broadcast inside service connection which depends upon the connection result. Connection result `onServiceConnected` takes some time after binding service. Same time if `onPause` gets called it throws an exception about not being registered.

Easy solution, just add null check for `networkServiceMessageReceiver`, if it is not null then only unregister as well once you are unregistering assigned it to null.